# ReferenceError: document is not defined (server making jsonP call)

Tags: node.js

I am using node.js and trying to make a jsonP call and getting the above error.
Its a server side call so once I get the result, all I want to do is to console.log it.

My code snippet is here.
https://npm.runkit.com/jsonp

Complete error is following.
ReferenceError: document is not defined
Reason: No document object in node.
RunKit is a node environment, so document and other browser features won’t exist.

Comment: You have answer in your question `No document object in node. RunKit is a node environment, so document and other browser features won’t exist.`

Comment: This is just a quick wrap example that I put together. 
https://runkit.com/embed/l5rlc3lqiv07

I have a similar call on my actual code and it is throwing the same error.

I am trying to make a jsonP call and console.log the result. how do I do that?

Comment: Just to clarify, I am making  my jsonP call from my controller.

This is a setup for the API calls, once the controller be called within routes, it will make a jsonP call, get the data, parse it and return it in different schema.